# Conditional merge SAS PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

In my original code, I want to merge several data bases:

```
%let theft=1;

proc sql;
create table NewTable as
Select *

From 
   dtm_sitecom.FactSitecAllCriteria SITEC

 left join dtm_sitecom.FactClaimLastVersion FactClaimLastVersion
    on FactClaimLastVersion.ClaimId = Sitec.ClaimId

/*Condition 1 here*/
/*If &Theft=1 then*/
 left join dtm_sitecom.DimClaimState DimClaimState
    on DimClaimState.ClaimStateKey = FactClaimLastVersion.ClaimStateKey

/*Condition 2 here*/
/*else if &Theft = 0 then*/
 left JOIN dtm_sitecom.DimGeoRisk dgr 
    ON dgr.GeoRiskKey = SITEC.GeoRiskKey;
quit;
```

On the upgraded version, I want to add some conditions (/*Condition 1*/ and /*Condition 2*/ in the code) such as, if the value of the variable `Theft=1` then do the merge with the talbe `dtm_sitecom.DimClaimState`, otherwise do the merge with the other table. I tried the code as if there is no comment sign around the `if`, but it didn't work because of the wrong syntax. Is there any SAS syntax allowing me to do that?

Comment: Give us an example of what you're trying to do.  The `on` clause *is* a condition, so what kind of condition are you trying to add that's not going to work there?

Comment: @Joe: I edited the question, I'm sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: If `theft=0` could you have any successful matches in `DimClaimState`?  Or are those only going to match when `theft=1`?

Comment: @Joe: `Theft` is just a variable assigned by `%let theft=1;`. So that in the begining of the program I can control which data to be merged, i.e I could have any sucessful matches.

Comment: `theft` is a macro variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are joining on a variable in the data, you can include that in the `on` statement:

```
data class_attach_m;
  set sashelp.class;
  attach_var='M';
run;

data class_attach_f;
  set sashelp.class;
  attach_var='F';
run;

proc sql;
  create table class as
    select class.*, coalescec(class_attach_m.attach_var,class_attach_f.attach_var) as attach_var from sashelp.class
    left join class_attach_m 
    on class.name = class_attach_m.name
      and class.sex='M'
    left join class_attach_f
    on class.name = class_attach_f.name
      and class.sex='F'
  ;
quit;
```

`coalescec` (or `coalesce` for numerics) combines the two brought-in fields.

If you are using macro variables to control which you run, though, you need to be running this in a macro; if you're in a macro context, you can use `%if` to control what is executed.

For example, using the previous example - and I use a macro parameter not a `%let` as that's the right way to do it, though you can define that parameter using `%let` earlier and use it for the parameter call:

```
%macro attach_which(attach_m=M);

proc sql;
  create table class as
    select class.*, attach_var from sashelp.class
    %if &attach_m=M %then %do;
      left join class_attach_m 
      on class.name = class_attach_m.name
    %end;
    %else %do;
      left join class_attach_f
      on class.name = class_attach_f.name
    %end;
  ;
quit;
%mend attach_which;

%attach_which(attach_m=M);
```

Comment: Effectively you replied perfectly to my question. Moreover, in the second part of your answer, does the code verify the conditions at every observations? If yes, is there a quicker way of doing this?

Comment: No, macro execution occurs before any data processing occurs.  The macro is writing the SQL code, and then that completed SQL code is submitted to the SQL interpreter.